# Simple QPSK transmiter, large sidelobes pulsation

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I have a simple flowgraph for QPSK transmitter with USRP.
[image]

After execution, there is lage sidelobes, that pulsate.
[image]
During the periods of large sidelobes, there is a drop in amplutude of main lobe.

There is no such pulsations if I make similar transmitter with Matlab.

I suscpect discontinues in sorce.

Comments and advice are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Your pool of random data is far too short; you'll see data periodicity in spectrum very quickly; it might be that this is exactly what happens. So, try with num_samples `2**20` instead.

  - You can observe your transmit spectrum yourself before even transmitting it: use the Qt GUI frequency sink or waterfall sink with an FFT length that corresponds to the FFT length you use in gqrx.
- Your sample rate is at the least end of all possible sampling rates. Here, the roll-off of the interpolation filters inside the USRP will definitely show. Don't do that to yourself. Use sps = 16, samp_rate = 1e6 instead.
- Make sure you're not getting any underruns in your tranmitter, nor overruns in your receiver. If that happens at these incredibly low sampling rates, something is wrong with your computer setup

Answer (score 0):

Changes make no difference. The following is @ 2**20 number of samples, 1 MHz sample rate and 20 samples per symbol. There is no underrun.
[image]

@ 5 Mhz sample rate I start receiving underrun.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and a solution.
The problem is that the level of the signal after modulator is too strong for the USRP input. After modulator the abs value of the signal reach 9. I don't know the maximum level of the signal that USRP expects. I presume something like 1 peak to peak
The solution is to restrict the level by multiplication with a constant. With constant=0.5, there is still distortions. Value of 0.2 is ok.
Here is the new flowgraph:
[image]